# Ubuntu 16.10 Wifi not working after sleep (XPS13)

Tags: wireless, suspend, xps

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 on my XPS 13 (9360) every time i close the lid or i put the laptop to suspension, WiFi stops working, even connecting to a different network (altough it connects) doesnt work. It looks as if was connected (showing signal and everything) but it's not. I have to  restart the computer to fix it...

It was working properly on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks!

The "lspci -knn" command, returns:

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:1904] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Dell Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [1028:0704]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 [8086:1916] (rev 07)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell HD Graphics 520 [1028:0704]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Dell Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [1028:0704]
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [1028:0704]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [1028:0704]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:15.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:9d60] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [1028:0704]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:9d61] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [1028:0704]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI [1028:0704]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:9d03] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1028:0704]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d10] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9d14] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:9d15] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:9d18] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d48] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [1028:0704]
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP PMC [1028:0704]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pmc_core
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [1028:0704]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [1028:0704]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0023]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [1028:0704]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:010f] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:0001]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn`.

Comment: Run `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service` after suspend and check if the wifi works.

Comment: The "sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service" command Worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and restarting network-manager fixed it for me as well. To automate this, add a script in /etc/pm/sleep.d with something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
  suspend)
    # executed on suspend
  ;;
  resume) 
    # executed on resume
    systemctl restart network-manager.service
  ;;
  *)
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: Sorry, can you please tell me how do i add this script? I'm new to linux. Thanks!