# DNS resolution not working after sleep

Tags: networking, suspend, dns

Whenever I wake my laptop up from sleep, my internet connection acts a bit weird. I can not resolve any domain names/hostnames until such time as I use `systemctl` to restart the network manager service.

Internet connectivity works, and I can reach systems by IP address, but not by domain name.

This happens both on wireless and wired connections, which makes me suspect that it's something weird with Ubuntu itself.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this issue besides re-running the service restart command every time I wake my system? Ideally, I'd like to implement a permanent solution instead of a [quick workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/872765/208574).

I'm running kernel version 4.4.0-63-generic on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, bothering me since a few months. Any way to fix this?